# Implementing functional addition in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was given a puzzle to do the following in Haskell,

> `f` takes two functions, function `a` and function `b`.  Function `a` takes  **n<sub>a</sub>** inputs and returns a `Num` type and function `b` takes **n<sub>b</sub>** inputs and returns a `Num` type.  `f` returns a new function of arity **n<sub>a</sub>+n<sub>b</sub>** that applies `a` to the first **n<sub>a</sub>** arguments, **n<sub>b</sub>** to the rest of the arguments and returns their sum.

In mathematics I would write this as:

[image: latex of formula]

My first naïve attempt at this in Haskell was:

```
f a b = flip ((+) . a) . b
```

But this only works if `a` is a unary function.

After this I thought about the puzzle for a long while without being able to come up with even an idea for how I might do this.  This is the first time in a long time I have been this utterly stumped in Haskell.

How might I solve this puzzle?  Is there a solution to this puzzle? *(I was given this puzzle by a friend and I don't believe they had a actual solution in mind at the time)*

Comment: Can we have an example in Haskell because there are two ways to interpret $f(a,b)$ in Haskell (i.e. do you want e.g. `f a b :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int` or `f a b :: Int -> Int -> Int`?)

Comment: The type of a function taking `n_a` inputs is `Vec n_a X -> Y` where `data Vec n a where Nil :: Vec 0 a; Cons ::a -> Vec n a -> Vec (1 + n) a`.

Comment: @DanRobertson Well strictly speaking we won't know `f a b` to have either of those types, because `f a b` might take any number of inputs.  However I think the intention of the puzzle is for a curried function, because having a tuple of arbitrary size is clearly impossible in Haskell.  (That being said currying in this way might be impossible, I'm just not sure of that in the way I am sure taking arbitrary tuples won't work)

Comment: Yes of course. I was using an arbitrary example to clarify whether you wanted currying or not or something odd like `Vec` above or some kind of typed homogeneous tuple-list hybrid. That clears things up.

Comment: @DanRobertson The puzzle was given to me as is, so I'd be interested in both/any type of solution.  Currying would be cool, but a solution is a solution, and I'm certainly not going to complain because I find the puzzle interesting, and new ways of thinking are probably good for me.

Comment: I’ve no solution I’m afraid.

Comment: The puzzle is ill-defined. A function type can have an instance of Num.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure what you are getting at.  Your statement is correct but I don't see how that relates to the puzzle being ill-defined.

Comment: For example, if you give `Int->Int` an instance of `Num` then say `(+)` is a two-argument function that returns a `Num` and is *also* a one-argument function that returns an instance of `Num`. There is no way *defined in the puzzle* to decide which interpretation you want.

Comment: @n.m. I suppose, would assume that we would probably be interested in the in the latter result.  However this is a really contrived case and I don't think it really matters what the function does when encountering this type of scenario.

Comment: You cannot tell the compiler "do whatever you want", you need to decide on something. The problem here is that neither decision is really expressible in Haskell. Try writing down one in an exact and detailed manner (either one). You will end up with things like "do this for all types which are *not* functions" or "which are *not* instances of `Num`", These things are not possible (with common safe extensions at any rate). You can say "do this thing for `Int` and that other thing for functions`, which is what the answer below does.

Comment: @n.m., something not being a function is quite easy to express with MPTC and a closed type family.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't understand closed type families well, cany you show how it's done?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a pretty simple approach using type families that works monomorphically in the numeric type (e.g., specialized to `Int`).  We'll need a few extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
```

The function `f` will be defined in a type class:

```
class VarArgs r s where
  type F r s
  f :: r -> s -> F r s
```

and we'll handle the following cases.  If the type of the first function is of form `a :: Int -> r`, we'll use the following instance to gobble an argument `x` and feed it to `a`:

```
instance VarArgs r s => VarArgs (Int -> r) s where
  type F (Int -> r) s = Int -> F r s
  f :: (Int -> r) -> s -> Int -> F r s
  f a b x = f (a x) b
```

This has the effect of recursing on the type of `a` until it's of the form `Int`.  Then, we'll use a similar instance to recurse on the type `b :: Int -> s`:

```
instance VarArgs Int s => VarArgs Int (Int -> s) where
  type F Int (Int -> s) = Int -> F Int s
  f :: Int -> (Int -> s) -> Int -> F Int s
  f a b x = f a (b x)
```

Ultimately, both functions will be reduced to 0-ary functions of type `a, b :: Int`, and we can use the terminal instance:

```
instance VarArgs Int Int where
  type F Int Int = Int
  f :: Int -> Int -> Int
  f a b = a + b
```

Here's a little test to prove it works:

```
times2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
times2 x y = x * y
times3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
times3 x y z = x * y * z

foo :: [Int]
foo = [ f times2 times2 1 2 3 4
      , f times2 times3 1 2 3 4 5
      , f times3 times2 1 2 3 4 5
      , f times3 times3 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

and loading this into GHCi gives:

```
> foo
[14,62,26,126]
>
```

Generalizing this to be polymorphic in any `Num` type doesn't seem to be straightforward.  Replacing the `Int` type with a constrained `Num n` type leads to errors regarding conflicting family instance declarations.

Comment: Upvoted, but I wouldn't call this a "pretty simple approach" ;-) It's not hard, but it's not exactly beginner's material.

Comment: Another small problem with this is that you *need* `times2`. Why not just `(*)`? `f (*) (*) 1 2 3 4` will produce a stream of errors, because the type of `(*)` is too good for `f`.

Comment: I suspect you're better off counting arrows than looking for `Int`. You'll miss `Num` instances for functions, but catch the rest.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy and simple - much simpler than @K.A.Buhr's type family approach, in my opinion - if you tweak your representation of an *n*-ary function, instead using a unary function of an *n*-dimensional vector.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Prelude hiding (splitAt)
import Data.Bifunctor
```

The usual suspects: (type-level) natural numbers, their (value-level) singletons, type-level addition, and vectors.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
data Natty n where
    Zy :: Natty Z
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)
type family n + m where
    Z + m = m
    S n + m = S (n + m)

data Vec n a where
    Nil :: Vec Z a
    (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
```

`splitAt` takes a runtime `Natty` - it needs to know at runtime where to split the vector - and a vector that is at least as long as the `Natty`.

```
splitAt :: Natty n -> Vec (n + m) a -> (Vec n a, Vec m a)
splitAt Zy xs = (Nil, xs)
splitAt (Sy n) (x :> xs) =
    let (ys, zs) = splitAt n xs
    in (x :> ys, zs)
```

Then your `f`, which I'm calling `splitApply`, is a straightforward application of `splitAt`.

```
splitApply :: Natty n -> (Vec n a -> b) -> (Vec m a -> c) -> Vec (n + m) a -> (b, c)
splitApply at f g xs = bimap f g $ splitAt at xs
```

(I haven't bothered to show the "add the results" part, because it's so simple that I bored myself writing it. You could argue that, since **Hask** is a monoidal category, `(,)` represents a sort of addition anyway.)

Comment: I think an `HList` probably fits better than a vector--the problem description doesn't indicate that the function arguments all have the same type. The whole thing works out about the same, except you have `++` instead of `+`. But to get maximal type inference, you probably also need to define dropping from both the right and the left.